# Resizing Giant images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, fancybox

I'm working on a project that uses the NYTimes API and FancyBox library to create a photo gallery of the most popular articles' photos.

Im having some serious trouble with fancybox (really new to javascript/jquery). The articles from the Times API have a "superjumbo" image, which is normally 24xx x 13xx pixels. Now, I for the life of me, cannot get this to resize when fancybox opens. The images are massive and overwhelm the screen. I've tried modifying the fancybox attributes using javascript, but that doesn't seem to work at all

```
    $("document").ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        maxHeight : 1280,
        maxWidth: 720,
        fitToView     : false,
        autoSize    : true,
        closeClick  : true,
        autoCenter : true,
        closeBtn : true
    });
});
```

At least, i'm not sure if that's correct. If anyone has any suggestions, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Side-note: For the images, I'm not downloading the images individually. My idea was to parse the json for the API and grab the image URLS. So, that's how I'm passing the data to my website.

Comment: have you tried setting `fitToView: true,`?

Comment: also make sure you add `type:"image"` for images parsed through scripts

Comment: I've tried fitToView, that didn't work. Will make sure i add type:image. haven't tried that yet.